# When to process Markdown?

Tags: php, input, user-input

I have a flavored version of Markdown implemented in my social web application. Everything works, but my question is: when should you convert the user input (Markdown) into HTML? Before  storing it in the database (so that only the HTML is stored in the database) or when the user requests to view it (store Markdown in database)?

Both methods have their pros and cons, but I could only come up with the following arguments:

- Storing the processed input in the database makes showing it faster, because we don't need to convert it anymore, it's ready for display.
- Processing it when viewed allows me to change the Markdown processor at any time, for example adding a feature that automatically parses Youtube urls to embeds.

What approach would you take and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a rule, always try to store data in its least processed state, because as you say you might change the way it's processed.  You can always recreate the processed data, but you can't recreate the original.

What if you want to add an "Edit" feature?  You'll need the markdown.

I'd store the Markdown and render it on demand, putting in a cache (which might be as simple as "store *both* formats in the database) if performance might be a problem.

Comment: I'd second storing both, if you don't anticipate the extra storage load causing a problem at whatever scale you're working.